# The bundle identifier should be added as a URL scheme to enable Google sign-in

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I am attempting to integrate Google Analytics and App Invites into my Swift project and am following this documentation to the letter:

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift
- https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/guides/app?configured=true&ver=swift

One omission in the latter is that you must add

```
#import <Google/AppInvite.h>
```

to your [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

Also, I added the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` from `GoogleService-Info.plist` into `Project -> Target -> Info -> URL Types -> URL Schemes` along with the Identifier `Google`, as discussed in the Google Sign In documentation.

However, during run, I receive the error `

> The bundle identifier should be added as a URL scheme to enable Google sign-in

I did not have Google sign-in selected when using Google "Enable Google services for your app" web tool, so this error is confusing and unexpected.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that error when trying to test on Simulator but works fine on device. It may just be it doesn't work in simulator?

Answer (score 4):

I added one more URL scheme to the project which is same as my Bundle identifier. It works now.

[image]

Here *"com.suresh.myApp"* is the bundle identifier of my application.